# Align the diagram with the top line

Tags: graph, elk, react-flow, dagre, flow-diagram

is it possible to create something like this using dagrejs / elkjs or something else? I need to align the diagram with the top line (node 1 -> node 2 -> node 6). All other branches should be positioned below. If we add a new step to the second branch, we need to continue the line for the main branch and the third branch. All lines should converge at node 6.

[image]

I tried reactflow + dagrejs / elkjs, but got the next result

[image]